# Passing href text and referencing web page in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Any way to do it using crawl spider? Not yielding requests. Just an example would suffice. I want to use the href text as the title of web page and have a link to the url that contained the link. I'm just using basic selectors to fill my item, but not sure how to get this information.

Edit:
I looked into it and I want to be able to pass in meta data of the href title and referencing url and also be able to comply with the rules I've defined rather than having to get all urls and conditioning on them myself.

meta={"hrefText" : ..., "refURL": ...}

Comment: Could you give an example to help clarify your requirement? Also what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

see [CrawlSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L56) code:

```
for link in links:
    r = Request(url=link.url, callback=self._response_downloaded)
    r.meta.update(rule=n, link_text=link.text)
    yield rule.process_request(r)
```

meaning you can get href text from `response.meta['link_text']`

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try it out.

Comment: How would I get the links from the processed pages as well? I want it to be recursive

Comment: see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules you have to set `follow=True`